# cppcoro::task<T> unclear how to suspend and resume task

Tags: c++, asynchronous, task, cppcoro

I am currently trying to implement code that starts a coroutine with [cppcoro's task coroutine type](https://github.com/lewissbaker/cppcoro#taskt) and after reading the [header code](https://github.com/lewissbaker/cppcoro/blob/master/include/cppcoro/task.hpp) it's still unclear to me how i could exactly get a handle for the coroutine to suspend/resume it.

A relatively simple example inspired by the code in the readme of cppcoro of what I am trying to do is below. For now it just executes the code even without me resuming anything, even though i gave the instruction to suspend always.

Any help is appreciated.

```
#include <cppcoro/sync_wait.hpp>
#include <cppcoro/task.hpp>
#include <cppcoro/coroutine.hpp>
#include <iostream>

cppcoro::task<int> getInt(int array[], int key)
{
    int result = array[key];
    // suspend here to return instruction to caller while data structure is being accessed
    cppcoro::suspend_always{};
    co_return result;
}

cppcoro::task<> scheduler()
{
    int array[2];
    array[0] = 1337;
    array[1] = 7331;

    // setting first task
    cppcoro::task<int> firstTask = getInt(array, 0);

    // setting second task 
    cppcoro::task<int> secondTask = getInt(array, 1);

    // starting first task 
    int firstResult = co_await firstTask;

    // starting second task after suspending first task while accessing
    int secondResult = co_await secondTask;
    
    // resume first task again if data access is done
    // insert resume first task here and output result

    // resume second task again is data access is done
    // insert resume second task here and output result

    std::cout << firstResult << std::endl;
    std::cout << secondResult << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    cppcoro::sync_wait(scheduler());
}
```

Edit: I looked up the Types and picked out [async_auto_reset_event](https://github.com/andreasbuhr/cppcoro#async_auto_reset_event) since it seems like it does what i want it to do, but the program stays suspended even if i used the function to resume execution.

```
#include <cppcoro/sync_wait.hpp>
#include <cppcoro/task.hpp>
#include <cppcoro/coroutine.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <cppcoro/async_auto_reset_event.hpp>
#include <cppcoro/static_thread_pool.hpp>
#include <cppcoro/when_all_ready.hpp>

cppcoro::async_auto_reset_event task0;
cppcoro::async_auto_reset_event task1;

cppcoro::task<int> getInt(int array[], int key, cppcoro::async_auto_reset_event& event)
{
    int result = array[key];
    // suspend here to return instruction to caller while data structure is being accessed
    std::cout << "about to suspend task " << key << std::endl;
    co_await event;
    std::cout << "resumed task " << key << std::endl;
    co_return result;
}

cppcoro::task<> scheduler()
{
    int array[2];
    array[0] = 1337;
    array[1] = 7331;

    cppcoro::static_thread_pool tp{ 1 };

    // starting first task
    std::cout << "starting task 0" << std::endl;
    auto firstResult = co_await getInt(array, 0, task0);

    // starting second task 
    std::cout << "starting task 1" << std::endl;
    auto secondResult = co_await getInt(array, 1, task1);

        
    // resume first task again if data access is done
    // insert resume first task here and output result
    // resuming first task 
    std::cout << "about to resume task 0" << std::endl;
    task0.set();

    // resume second task again is data access is done
    // insert resume second task here and output result
    // resuming second task
    std::cout << "about to resume task 1" << std::endl;
    task1.set();

    std::cout << firstResult << std::endl;
    std::cout << secondResult << std::endl;
    co_return;
}

int main()
{
    //scheduler();
    cppcoro::sync_wait(cppcoro::when_all_ready(scheduler()));
}
```

Comment: what have you tried? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Actually nothing much because I don't know how to put it into code. But I just added some code with the stuff i know explaining what i am trying to do.

Comment: Simply constructing the `suspend_always` object does nothing. You'll need to use one of the scheduler types provided to have getInt be suspended and be able to resume it later. Alternatively, you can model getInt as a `generator<optional<int>>`, yield a nullopt when you want to "suspend", yield the value when you want to complete, and await on that generator until awaits its first non-nullopt value.

Comment: I just tried using the Type async_auto_reset_event since it seems like it does what i need it to do but it stays suspended with my current implementation.